# React native Linking open url not working with facebook link on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking

Thanks in advance.

Am trying to open a facebook page/profile url using the Linking component.

I used the below code.

```
 Linking.canOpenURL('fb://profile/<PAGE ID or PROFILE ID>').then(supported => {
            if (supported) { 
                return Linking.openURL('fb://profile/<PAGE ID or PROFILE ID>');
            } else { 
                return Linking.openURL('https://facebook.com/XXXXX');
            }
        });
```

When I use the above code in iOS it opens in browser not the facebook app, even though I have it in my phone.

Am getting the below error if I put the same code (if block) in else part.

```
2021-08-25 12:02:14.853723+0530[793:75609] [default] Failed to open URL fb://profile/xxxxxx: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=229, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}
2021-08-25 12:02:16.877524+0530[793:71906] [javascript] Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: Unable to open URL: fb://profile/xxxxxx
```

I Also Added `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`
with facebook and fb as item in plist file

Comment: I Also Added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
with facebook and fb as item in plist file

Answer (score 0):

After lot research I found a solution.

```
fb://profile?id=<PAGE_NAME OR PAGE_ID>
```

even if you are trying to open a profile or page use fb://profile.
I think fb://page no longer exists.

Make sure you update `Info.plist` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

```
[fb, facebook]
```